# ReadFile function returns error 23

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to read the data from a USB device (Windows 7), but I get an error 23 (ERROR_CRC). This is my code:

int main( int argc, char*argv[])
{
    HANDLE file;
    file = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, NULL);

    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        std::cout << "ERROR opening\n";
    }

    DWORD byte_count;
    GET_LENGTH_INFORMATION source_disklength;
    if(!DeviceIoControl(file, IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO, NULL, 0, &source_disklength, sizeof(source_disklength), &byte_count, NULL ) ){
        std::cout << "Error "<< GetLastError() << " getting device length \n";

    }
    std::cout << "DISK Length has " << source_disklength.Length.QuadPart << " bytes\n";

    int count = 0;

    DWORD cbRead;
    uint8_t buffer[50 * 1024];
    while (ReadFile(file, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &cbRead, NULL))
    {
          ++count;

    }           

    std::cout << "Read Error " << GetLastError() <<std::endl;    
        return 0;
}

The result is:

DISK Length has 16013942784 bytes

Read Error 23

Does somebody know why GetLastError() returns an error and what exactly is the meaning of the error?

Comment: 23 is `ERROR_CRC` if I'm not mistaking. Double-check that your file is not corrupted?

Comment: Yes, 23 is ERROR_CRC but I don't know why I receive this error. I tried with two more usb memory devices and the result is the same.

Comment: Are you getting that error only when you reach the end of the disk, or immediately?  Might be a good idea to have the message include the value of `count` so you can tell.  Also, if this is a memory stick or other SSD device it might use 4096-byte sectors, so you should probably make the read length a multiple of 4096, e.g., `52 * 1024`.

Comment: I am getting the error after reaching the end. Now I tried with buffer[52 * 1024] and 8GB flash memory and the result is:                               DISK Length has 8012390400 bytes
Read Error 23 count = 150473

Comment: So, the read bytes from the memory are 8012386304, which is exactly 4096 bytes less than the size.